# django message alert exit button doesn't work

Tags: html, django

I'm new in django.
I try to use the message alert to highlight the succes in  posting new item to the display. I try to do it using  bootsrtrap . Alert window includes exit button 'x' to dismiss alert.
Message window works but the exit button  doesn't  and I can't figure out why.

My home html:

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}

    {% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      {{ message }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
    

{% if list_items %}
{% for item in list_items %}
{{ item.item }} |{{ item.completed }}<br>

{% endfor %}
{% endif %}




{% endblock %}




</body>
</html>}
```

base.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">To do list</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">



      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Add to list" aria-label="Search" name="item" required>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
     <div class="container">
    {% block content %}

{% endblock %}
         </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
              integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </body>
</html>
```

My view:

```
from django.contrib import messages
...
...
messages.success(request,('Succes'))
```

Can you tell me, why it doesn't work?

Comment: maybe because your missing the type of the button ? . eg  `<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">`

Comment: I have tried it. It doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you haven't mentioned you are using bootstrap but from your HTML it's pretty obvious. Please try to include all details when asking a question, it helps everyone.

The problem here is one of grammar/spelling mistake. You have written `.alert-dismissable` but it actually is `alert-dismissible`. ([reference to bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/alerts/#dismissing))

In any case, this should work:

```html
{% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
          {{ message }}
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT: Updated answer for bootstrap 5.0**

Comment: I have tried it and it does't work . Button 'x' when displayed looks not being styled by bootstrap however i pasted bootstrap link at the beginning and another features work.

Comment: Are you sure you have included _all_ the booststrap links ? Especially the jquery one. I'd recommend opening the console in the browser, clicking on the "x" and see if anything gets logged to the console and then update your question with a screenshot of the console. We can't help you debug with no information.

Comment: I have pasted jquery link one more time. My console shows only "Ciasteczko 'messages' zostało odrzucone, ponieważ już utraciło ważność" with means "Cookie"'messages' has been discarded becouse of  being expired. It shows anything else during clicking  'x' button.

Comment: Please update your question with the entire HTML file.

Comment: You are using bootstrap 5.0 CDN but you are probably following docs of 4.0. I have updated my answer for 5.0 and the bootstrap docs link as well. This is why you should always include full code and all details when asking a question. I hope the problem is solved now and please consider marking the answer as "accepted".

Comment: Now it works. I write down code from tutorial but

Answer (score 0):

did you add all of the bootstrap cdns?
Jquery  , Js , min css?
Can you try this code? I followed bootstrap:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible " role="alert"> <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"><small><sup>x</sup></small> </span></button> {{message }} </div>
```